# Retaining ViewModel in fragments

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

I'm collaborating with `ViewModel` and fragments, and would like to retain my `ViewModel` for my fragment on rotation change. When passing my `Fragment` into `ViewModelProviders.of()` it does not get retained, but when I pass the `Activity` that the fragment belongs to, it is retained. So is passing the activity how it is supposed to be used? 
Calling `ViewModelProviders.of(this)` in `Fragment` won't retain my `ViewModel`. Is that expected behavior?

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    fun OnXXXXXXXXX {
        // This _will NOT_ retain ViewModel
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

        // This _will_ retain ViewModel
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
    }
}
```

Comment: Call this `ViewModelProviders.of(this)` in Activity, while call this `ViewModelProviders.of(activity)` in Fragment with that you can get the same instance of ViewModel (note: Do it inside `onActivityCreated()`).

Comment: Yes, but calling `ViewModelProviders.of(this)` in `Fragment` won't retain my `ViewModel`. Is that expected behavior? @Enzokie

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its expected behaviour, Look at [this content](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing)

> Fragments can share a ViewModel using their activity scope to handle this communication

If you want to share same ViewModel, use same context. For Example, multiple fragments on same activity:

```
ViewModelProviders.of(activity)
```